# how to go back after finishing the activity of sending email

Tags: android, android-activity, start-activity

I have a fragment that has a send button.

On click of a send button, the activity is started to Choose an Email client from device.

Once we choose email client and sends the mail, it returns to the fragment again as expected.

But there is no need to have a fragment view as our mail sending task is finished.

So we want to come back to the previous activity after the mail is sent successfully.

How to do that?

I tried:

`getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();`

But that doesn't worked.

My code on send button click is :

```
view.findViewById(R.id.sendbtn).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"),2);
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(); //this is not working to go back.
}
});
```

Comment: Is this Fragment actually added to the back stack?

Comment: Yes, this fragment also contains the back button and on click of that I have this: `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();` which is taking me to back fragment activity view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to remove the fragment after you have send the mail(fixed):

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(MailFragment.this).commit();
```

But remember that it can be removed only if it was added dynamically using `FragmentTransaction` and the `.add()` method. If the fragment was added in XML, remove method won't work.

To add a fragment dynamically you should do this:

```
MailFragment mailFragment = new MailFragment(); 

FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.containerForFragments, mailFragment).commit();
```

Then you can remove this fragment via the `.remove()` method.

By the way instead of removing the fragment you can try just hide it (will not be removed from memory):

```
 getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(MailFragment.this).commit();
```

Comment: this is giving me the syntax error:`getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().remove(MailFragment.this);`. The method remove(MailFragment) is undefined for the type FragmentManager.

Comment: sorry, I missed something in the answer, please try it now.

Comment: I have no fragment defined in xml but my class MailFragment is extending fragment. Is it still fine to add fragment like this?

Comment: Yes, this is the way to add fragment dynamically to your layout.

Comment: thanks for the help..actually I was having most of the same code in two classes: one in fragment and other in activity. The activity class was the one where the control was going. I just used `finish()` after `startActivityForResult` method and it worked..

Comment: this is an option as well. If I was helpful, you can accept/vote the answer.